# "org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Element type "Listeners" must be declared. while working on listeners

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, listener

I am working on TestNG Listener to generate Extent Report, and then I am getting the following Exception.

> **org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 12; Element type "Listeners" must be
>   declared.**

The same is the issue observed while working with ITestListener. So the problem may entirely be with the Listeners. Please help me in this regard.

*My Test Environment is as mentioned below.
selenium-java: version- 3.141.59
testng: version- 6.14.3
Java: version- 1.8*

I have tried adding ExtentReport dependencies either latest or older versions from com.aventstack along with the old com.relevantcodes versions as below

> com.aventstack
>       extentreports
>       4.0.9 OR 3.1.5  along with 
>       com.relevantcodes
>       extentreports
>       2.41.2 OR 2.41.1

I also have tried giving listener information either in Testng.xml or in the class implementing the listener or in both

*1. Testng.xml file   "/>  or
2. Directly using @Listeners annotation in the class which is implementing Listener @Listeners({.class})*

Please find code as below

**POM.xml file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>Jesus_Practise</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Jesus_Practise</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**testng.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="FreeCRM Test Suite">
<Listeners>
<Listener class-name="com.qa.Listeners.ExtentReporterNG"/>
<Listener class-name="com.qa.Listeners.ITestListen"/>
</Listeners>
    <test thread-count="5" name="FreeCRM Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qa.testcases.LoginPageTest" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Reporter**

```
package com.qa.Listeners;

import java.io.File;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.testng.IReporter;
import org.testng.IResultMap;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteResult;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;    
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

@Listeners({ExtentReporterNG.class})
public class ExtentReporterNG implements IReporter{

    private ExtentReports extent;

    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites,
            String outputDirectory) {
        extent = new ExtentReports(outputDirectory + File.separator
                + "Extent.html", true);

        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
            Map<String, ISuiteResult> result = suite.getResults();

            for (ISuiteResult r : result.values()) {
                ITestContext context = r.getTestContext();

                buildTestNodes(context.getPassedTests(), LogStatus.PASS);
                buildTestNodes(context.getFailedTests(), LogStatus.FAIL);
                buildTestNodes(context.getSkippedTests(), LogStatus.SKIP);
            }
        }

        extent.flush();
        extent.close();
    }

    private void buildTestNodes(IResultMap tests, LogStatus status) {
        ExtentTest test;

        if (tests.size() > 0) {
            for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
                test = extent.startTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());

                test.setStartedTime(getTime(result.getStartMillis()));
                test.setEndedTime(getTime(result.getEndMillis()));

                for (String group : result.getMethod().getGroups())
                    test.assignCategory(group);

                if (result.getThrowable() != null) {
                    test.log(status, result.getThrowable());
                } else {
                    test.log(status, "Test " + status.toString().toLowerCase()
                            + "ed");
                }

                extent.endTest(test);
            }
        }
    }

    private Date getTime(long millis) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your suite xml file.

The correct way of defining listeners in a suite xml file is to use the tag `<listeners></listeners>`. Your suite xml has them defined as `<Listeners></Listeners>` and `<Listener>` respectively. Please fix your tags to be defined in all small case.

Your tags begin with a capital letter.